# JGroups ReplicatedHashMap in a cluster

Tags: java, caching, cluster-computing, jgroups

My Spring based web app is deployed to production in a Tomcat cluster (4+ nodes) with sticky sessions. The max number of nodes will not exceed 8-10 in a few years time.

I need to cache some data(mostly configuration), to avoid hitting Oracle. Since the nature of this data is mostly configuration, I would say the ratio of reads to writes is 999999 / 1.

I don't want to use a full-blown caching solution such as Infinispan/Hazelcast/Redis as it adds operation complexity to the product and the requirement is to cache some small, mostly read-only data(let's say a few hundred kilobytes the most)

At first, I wanted to implement a simple replicating map myself, then I saw `[JGroups][1]` ships with a `[ReplicatedHashMap][1]`. I think it suits my needs but I'm not sure whether I'm missing something.

What else should I consider?
Has anyone used it in production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReplicatedHashMap is one class of 700 lines, so it isn't particularly complex, and uses JGroups, which has been used for decade(s) in production.

If you need something simple, without transactions/overflow-store etc, then it might be right for your job. Note that you could modify it and/or write your own, with RHM as template.

RHM replicates all data to all nodes, so if you have many nodes (you don't), or your data is large, then ReplCache may be the better choice.

Comment: Thank you Bela Ban for your input. 
One of the things I want to store in the cache is encryption key, now as I see `ReplicatedHashMap` is using UDP protocol to sync nodes, what happens if one of the nodes fails to receive a rotated key? Encrypting data with the obsolete encryption key is a no-no, so maybe my requirements require transactions after all.
Can I continue using UDP for discovery and TCP for sync in JGroups?

Comment: Note that RHM can use *any* configuration, be it UDP or TCP. A node will eventually (by means of retransmission) receive *all* messages, unless it crashes.